# List all available Handlebar Templates in the JavaScript console

Tags: ember.js

How can I list all available handlebar templates with their names in the JavaScript console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `Ember.keys`:

```
Ember.keys(Ember.TEMPLATES);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Ember.keys(Ember.TEMPLATES) to view all registered templates..

For further info [Refer this](http://www.akshay.cc/blog/2013-02-22-debugging-ember-js-and-ember-data.html)

---