# Get all available Templates in Ember

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to get all available templates in Ember, as of 2.16.x `Ember.TEMPLATES` doesn't seem to work anymore. Basically I need exactly this, is there an alternative?

I'm trying to dynamically load a route's template based on a model property. I already have the logic working, all I need is a list of the templates.

Related, but doesn't work anymore: [List all available Handlebar Templates in the JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204973/list-all-available-handlebar-templates-in-the-javascript-console)

Thanks!

Comment: I do something similar. But I don't need the list of all templates, I can determine the template name based on the model property and then just render it. Any chance you can do it without having the list of all templates?

Comment: No, I definitely need a list of all available templates in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all of the `entries` via `window.requirejs.entries`. If all your templates are fitting some naming or directory rules then you can find the list of them. For example, if all of your templates resides under `templates` directory, you can find them as following:

```
var getKeys = (Object.keys || Ember.keys);
getKeys(window.requirejs.entries).forEach(itemName=>{
  if(itemName.indexOf('templates')>=0){
    console.log(itemName, itemName.indexOf('templates')>=0);
    console.log(window.requirejs.entries[itemName]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me so far. Although I changed it to `Object.keys(window.requirejs.entries).filter((path) => path.includes('custom-path'));` (ES6)

Comment: Sure, as [List all available Handlebar Templates in the JavaScript console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204973/list-all-available-handlebar-templates-in-the-javascript-console) solutions are not working anymore. This solution may be broken at some day.

Comment: I don't really understand why they would remove `Ember.keys(Ember.TEMPLATES);` in the first place, it's a much more elegant solution.